# How to call a table-valued UDF in Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, sql, entity-framework, user-defined-functions

I've been learning to use the .net Entity Framework for an ASP.net web application.  My goal is to re-write a small Classic ASP web application using ASP.net MVC.

So far, everything has been great, but I cannot, for the life of me, seem to be able to figure out how to use a table-values UDF (user-defined function) using the Entity Framework.  We extensively use UDFs in-line in our SQL queries.

One of our functions returns a list of location ID numbers and corresponding location names and other data.  This function is called `fn_getLocationData(@year)`.  There is a seperate list of locations for each year, so @year specifies what year to get locations for.

We have a lot of queries that look something like this:

```
SELECT E2L.employeeName, E2L.locationId, L.locationName
FROM
    EmployeeToLocation E2L
INNER JOIN
    fn_getLocationData(2012) L
    ON E2L.locationId = L.locationId
```

If I cannot find an easy way to use the results of calling `fn_getLocationData` in the Entity Framework, then the Entity Framework will be a complete non-starter in my organization.

I need to know how to set up my `edmx` model and associated code to allow me to use my UDFs.  Please help.

Comment: There is an article here: http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/calling-udfs-from-entity-framework-not-what-you-might-have-expected/ about calling scalar values UDFs, but it doesn't seem to do what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Table valued functions are not supported yet. The support was part of June 2011 CTP which will be released in .NET 4.5.